# eventually monotone sequences $(f_n(x))_{x=N}^\infty$, $x\in I$

Tags: real-analysis

A real-valued sequence $(x_n)$ is called monotone if it is either increasing (i.e. $x_{n+1}\geq x_n$ for all $n$) or decreasing (i.e. $x_{n+1}\leq x_n$ for all $n$). Let $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$. Suppose that for each $x\in [0,1]$, the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n=1}^\infty$ is eventually monotone (that is, there exists $N_x\in\Bbb N$ such that the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n=N_x}^\infty$ is monotone). Show that there exists an open interval $I\subseteq [0,1]$ and $N\in\Bbb N$ such that the sequences $(f_n(x))_{x=N}^\infty$, $x\in I$ are either all increasing or all decreasing.

The question seems interesting to me. I would be glad if someone could help me to solve the problem. I found a link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844870/baire-category-for-monotonic-sequence)

But, I couldn't understand how we use Baire Category Theorem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is a complete metric space, you can invoke Baire's Theorem which says that the union of a countable collection of closed nowhere dense sets has empty interior. In particular, since $X=\cup A_{n}$ and the collection $\{A_{n}\}_{n}$ satisfies the previous hypothesis (to see this, assume by contradiction that what you want to prove is false and convince yourself that this implies that every $A_{n}$ is nowhere dense), you get that $\mathrm{int}(X)=\emptyset$. This is a contradiction because the whole space is open and is non empty by hypotesis.